# NLmeans / ffmpeg: is it really SO slow?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to encode DVD-quality video with ffmpeg and **nlmeans** filtering (well, that's what the title says). But even on the top Core i7 CPU I have barely 12 frames per sec, and only one core is in use (75% idle). On older machines it's less than 1-2 fps.

Is it really so slow, or it's just me? No multithreading? No GPU optimization?

Default settings, windows7x64, zeranoe build.

Comment: NLmeans is multithreaded but x86 CPU extensions aren't used yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've used FFMpeg and I can confirm that you can see surprisingly slow frame times.  I've experienced 30% total usage on an i7 core with 2 solid cores.  Adding another compression stream bumped the CPU up to 70% at which point I abandoned that approach (4 streams were needed and a maxed-out CPU was not an option).
I think that as FFMpeg is written with very low-level requirements (ie you can run it on microcontrollers if you wish!) it doesn't natively use all your MMX/SIMD magic extensions etc.  Also you're likely to be compressing on only a single thread.

Good Luck!